# Не компилируется простейший исходный текст на C++

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, строковый-литерал

Помогите. Непонятно почему не компилируется.
Linux debian 8/g++ 4.9.2

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *p = "po";
    cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> 1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’: 1.cpp:7:11: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
>   [-Wwrite-strings] char *p = "po"; ^

Comment: Не компилируется - это означает, что компилятор выдает какое-то сообщение об ошибке, не так ли? Что это за сообщение?

Comment: какая ошибка при компиляции?

Comment: 1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
1.cpp:7:11: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 char *p = "po";
           ^

Comment: @user233952 добавьте это в описании ошибки

Comment: Спасибо. Но даже на сайте на другом все компилируется..
во всем виноват GCC 9.4.2 ??

Comment: общаться принято в комментариях

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/135414)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/135414)

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то [компилируется и работает](http://cpp.sh/5igd).

Но что значит "не компилируется"? Просто молча не компилируется и все тут? Черный экран? Проверьте, включен ли компьютер в электрическую сеть...

А если он что-то сообщает - то, может, поделитесь? очень трудно расходовать телепатические возможности в воскресенье...

**Update**
Вас просто предупредили, что в присвоении

```
char *p = "po";
```

`p` имеет тип `char`, а `"po"` - `const char[]`, так что вы можете непреднамеренно попытаться изменить константный литерал. Что делать категорически не рекомендуется - можно получить неприятности.

В вашем случае проще всего написать

```
const char *p = "po";
```

Comment: 1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
1.cpp:7:11: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 char *p = "po";
           ^

Answer (score 2):

Если не учитывать специфику проектов для тех или иных компиляторов, то я вижу единственную причину, что код не компилируется компилятором C++: в С++ строковые литералы имеют тип константных символьных массивов. Поэтому следует написать

```
const char *p = "po";
```

Этот код может компилироваться другими компиляторами для обеспечения совместимости со старым кодом. Кроме того строковые литералы в C  в отличии от C++ сохраняют эту совместимость со старым кодом, так как квалификатор `const` был не сразу введен в язык C. Поэтому в C строковые литералы имеют тип неконстантных символьных массивов. Для C программы данное объявление совершенно корректно

```
char *p = "po";
```

Тем не менее ни в C++, ни в C строковые литералы нельзя изменять даже несмотря на что в последнем случае они имеют тип неконстантных символьных массивов. Поэтому, например, если в программе на C (не говоря уж о программе на C++) вы напишите

```
char *p = "po";
p[0] = 'q';
```

то программа будет иметь неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 0):

Надо так:

```
const char *p = "po";
```